# libldap-2.4.2.dylib not loaded after switch php version

Tags: php, macos, homebrew

I get this error `dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openldap/lib/libldap-2.4.2.dylib` when switch php verison back to `8.0`.

I can fix it by `brew reinstall php@8.0`, but it will happend again when switch verison.

I am using MacOS Big Sur 11.4, but Mojave also got this problem.

**My flow**

```
$ php -v
PHP 7.4.19 (cli) (built: May 29 2021 10:41:11) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.0.4, Copyright (c) 2002-2021, by Derick Rethans
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.19, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
(base)

$ brew install shivammathur/php/php@8.0

$ php -v
PHP 8.0.6 (cli) (built: May 14 2021 07:18:20) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.6, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.6, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
(base)

$ brew unlink php && brew link --overwrite --force php@7.4

$ php -v
PHP 7.4.19 (cli) (built: May 29 2021 10:41:11) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.0.4, Copyright (c) 2002-2021, by Derick Rethans
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.19, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
(base)

$ brew unlink php && brew link --overwrite --force php@8.0

$ php -v
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openldap/lib/libldap-2.4.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/php
  Reason: image not found
[1]    91532 abort      php -v
(base)
```

**Package info**

```
$ brew info php@7.4 php@8.0 openldap libiconv
php@7.4: stable 7.4.19 (bottled) [keg-only]
General-purpose scripting language
https://www.php.net/
/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.19 (494 files, 72.3MB)
  Built from source on 2021-05-29 at 10:42:03
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/php@7.4.rb
License: PHP-3.01
==> Dependencies
Build: httpd ✔, pkg-config ✔
Required: apr ✔, apr-util ✔, argon2 ✔, aspell ✔, autoconf ✔, curl ✔, freetds ✔, gd ✔, gettext ✔, glib ✔, gmp ✔, icu4c ✔, krb5 ✔, libffi ✔, libpq ✔, libsodium ✔, libzip ✔, oniguruma ✔, openldap ✔, openssl@1.1 ✔, pcre2 ✔, sqlite ✔, tidy-html5 ✔, unixodbc ✔
==> Caveats
To enable PHP in Apache add the following to httpd.conf and restart Apache:
    LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php@7.4/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so

    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>

Finally, check DirectoryIndex includes index.php
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

The php.ini and php-fpm.ini file can be found in:
    /usr/local/etc/php/7.4/

php@7.4 is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because this is an alternate version of another formula.


To have launchd start php@7.4 now and restart at login:
  brew services start php@7.4
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  php-fpm
==> Analytics
install: 34,679 (30 days), 89,314 (90 days), 165,001 (365 days)
install-on-request: 34,481 (30 days), 88,821 (90 days), 164,225 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)

php: stable 8.0.6 (bottled), HEAD
General-purpose scripting language
https://www.php.net/
/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.4.12 (495 files, 72.2MB)
  Built from source
/usr/local/Cellar/php@8.0/8.0 (494 files, 77.5MB) *
  Built from source on 2021-04-09 at 09:59:53
/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.6 (500 files, 77.8MB)
  Poured from bottle on 2021-05-29 at 17:48:14
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/php.rb
License: PHP-3.01
==> Dependencies
Build: httpd ✔, pkg-config ✔
Required: apr ✔, apr-util ✔, argon2 ✔, aspell ✔, autoconf ✔, curl ✔, freetds ✔, gd ✔, gettext ✔, glib ✔, gmp ✔, icu4c ✔, krb5 ✔, libffi ✔, libpq ✔, libsodium ✔, libzip ✔, oniguruma ✔, openldap ✔, openssl@1.1 ✔, pcre2 ✔, sqlite ✔, tidy-html5 ✔, unixodbc ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Caveats
To enable PHP in Apache add the following to httpd.conf and restart Apache:
    LoadModule php_module /usr/local/opt/php/lib/httpd/modules/libphp.so

    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>

Finally, check DirectoryIndex includes index.php
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

The php.ini and php-fpm.ini file can be found in:
    /usr/local/etc/php/8.0/

To start php:
  brew services start php
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  /usr/local/opt/php/sbin/php-fpm --nodaemonize
==> Analytics
install: 59,614 (30 days), 153,695 (90 days), 636,046 (365 days)
install-on-request: 58,355 (30 days), 150,786 (90 days), 621,760 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)

openldap: stable 2.5.4 (bottled) [keg-only]
Open source suite of directory software
https://www.openldap.org/software/
/usr/local/Cellar/openldap/2.5.4 (339 files, 7.0MB)
  Poured from bottle on 2021-05-29 at 10:13:28
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/openldap.rb
License: OLDAP-2.8
==> Dependencies
Required: openssl@1.1 ✔
==> Caveats
openldap is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because macOS already provides this software and installing another version in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

If you need to have openldap first in your PATH, run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openldap/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openldap/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find openldap you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openldap/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openldap/include"

For pkg-config to find openldap you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openldap/lib/pkgconfig"

==> Analytics
install: 119,420 (30 days), 336,001 (90 days), 1,036,075 (365 days)
install-on-request: 14,088 (30 days), 46,874 (90 days), 166,063 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)

libiconv: stable 1.16 (bottled) [keg-only]
Conversion library
https://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/
/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.16 (30 files, 2.4MB)
  Poured from bottle on 2021-05-29 at 15:10:22
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/libiconv.rb
License: GPL-3.0
==> Caveats
libiconv is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because macOS already provides this software and installing another version in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

If you need to have libiconv first in your PATH, run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/libiconv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find libiconv you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/libiconv/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/libiconv/include"

==> Analytics
install: 5,992 (30 days), 14,923 (90 days), 60,385 (365 days)
install-on-request: 4,364 (30 days), 10,383 (90 days), 39,784 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)
(base)
```

Answer (score 1):

Got this problem after a a complete update to my system.

As of now PHP 7.1 and lower are deprecated from Homebrew (gives warning for 7.2)

This should work any but 7.2 and lower:

```
brew reinstall php@8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue with php@7.3, could solve it with
brew reinstall php@7.3

```
   Process:               php [34964]
Path:                  /usr/local/Cellar/php@7.3/7.3.28/bin/php
Identifier:            php
Version:               0
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        zsh [33976]
Responsible:           Terminal [33974]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2021-05-29 14:54:16.027 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.15.7 (19H1030)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        27971833-8B1A-565F-AF38-850B51BFF263

Sleep/Wake UUID:       97FB53F8-E8CE-4D13-8B18-35E70FBE222C

Time Awake Since Boot: 200000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       15000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    DYLD, [0x1] Library missing

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openldap/lib/libldap-2.4.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/php@7.3/bin/php
  Reason: image not found

Binary Images:
       0x10ed4c000 -        0x10f8adff3 +php (0) <A7799EE4-0502-34CF-8C19-00E2B238B154> /usr/local/opt/php@7.3/bin/php
       0x10faa3000 -        0x10fc62d03 +libcrypto.1.1.dylib (0) <EF694AAC-B437-322C-B619-BF3EB122466C> /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libcrypto.1.1.dylib
       0x10fcff000 -        0x10fd4eff7 +libssl.1.1.dylib (0) <9BD08628-AC20-3489-B3D2-AC117A5BC2F8> /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib
       0x10fd81000 -        0x10fd91fff +libzip.5.dylib (0) <01712EF1-7BA0-3073-ACE4-806C184CE3D5> /usr/local/opt/libzip/lib/libzip.5.dylib
       0x10fd9c000 -        0x10fe1bff3 +libtidy.5.dylib (0) <75C59099-9522-3701-8A22-276C6B65F9AF> /usr/local/opt/tidy-html5/lib/libtidy.5.dylib
       0x10fe5e000 -        0x10fe62ff7 +libargon2.1.dylib (0) <21EA0947-B6AC-33CF-98FF-2458872E1B8D> /usr/local/opt/argon2/lib/libargon2.1.dylib
       0x10fe6a000 -        0x10fea9ffb +libsodium.23.dylib (0) <D8777AB1-B4BA-324E-8E40-FEF56A1E7955> /usr/local/opt/libsodium/lib/libsodium.23.dylib
       0x10fec0000 -        0x10ff0bff3 +libaspell.15.dylib (0) <EE2F1867-CC5D-3417-802E-BF346085A7EC> /usr/local/opt/aspell/lib/libaspell.15.dylib
       0x10ff4b000 -        0x10ff4efff +libpspell.15.dylib (0) <BCDE5138-A654-30CB-BFFC-AA8C02A5F181> /usr/local/opt/aspell/lib/libpspell.15.dylib
       0x10ff53000 -        0x10ff8afff +libpq.5.dylib (0) <A33CB55C-781A-3D74-B9AB-2DD5DD90FB81> /usr/local/opt/libpq/lib/libpq.5.dylib
       0x10ffa0000 -        0x110083ffb +libsqlite3.0.dylib (0) <D721F2B6-F556-3C4C-9D2F-5C5A6B004EF6> /usr/local/opt/sqlite/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib
       0x1100af000 -        0x1100fefff +libsybdb.5.dylib (0) <8308AD20-05F2-3C4B-906D-4503DB597CFB> /usr/local/opt/freetds/lib/libsybdb.5.dylib
       0x11f328000 -        0x11f3b9f47  dyld (750.6) <1DCAF85D-70A4-3405-A868-25AF3DC1F32B> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff6e04a000 -     0x7fff6e067fff  libedit.3.dylib (55) <96858F68-DEB8-3CEE-B920-C2CF13B96D30> /usr/lib/libedit.3.dylib
    0x7fff6e082000 -     0x7fff6e08effb  libexslt.0.dylib (16.11) <08008EC9-B665-34B6-96AA-3E4D0AD401B7> /usr/lib/libexslt.0.dylib
    0x7fff6eabb000 -     0x7fff6eaeafff  libncurses.5.4.dylib (57) <995DFEEA-40F3-377F-B73D-D02AC59D591F> /usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib
    0x7fff6f23e000 -     0x7fff6f256fff  libresolv.9.dylib (67.40.1) <C57EDFEF-D36A-310B-8D14-8C68A625B1E8> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
    0x7fff6f813000 -     0x7fff6f825ff3  libz.1.dylib (76) <793D9643-CD83-3AAC-8B96-88D548FAB620> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
```

Comment: I update brew and reinstall again, it works. Seem like this tap update: https://github.com/shivammathur/homebrew-php/issues/320

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to run `brew install openldap libiconv`

For compilers to find libiconv you may need to set:

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/libiconv/lib"

export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/libiconv/include"
```

Look out and see if openldap is already installed and run `brew upgrade openldap`

If you need to have php@7.4 first in your PATH, run:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@8.0/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@8.0/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Finally run `brew services start php@8.0`

Comment: I upgrade openldap to 2.5.5, but still have problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I upgraded my PHP version from 7.3 to 8.0 on macOS Monterey. I resolved the issue with the following steps

```
brew reinstall openldap
brew reinstall php@8.0
brew services restart php@8.0
```

Then I exported php@8.0 to my PATH variable to have it first in my PATH.
And lastly, I restarted my laptop and everything worked fine.